# Check if the given string is a date object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check whether the given string is date object or not.

Initially I used

```
 Date.parse(val)
```

If you check `Date.parse("07/28/2014 11:23:29 AM")`, it'll work.

But if you check `Date.parse("hi there 1")`, it'll work too, which shouldn't.

So I changed my logic to

```
val instanceof Date
```

But for my above date string, `"07/28/2014 11:23:29 AM" instanceof Date` it returns `false`.

So, is there any way with which I can appropriately validate my string against Date?

Comment: try to replace date string `07/28/2014 11:23:29 AM` to `29-07-2014 11:23:29 AM`

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Date.parse` to check if it is a date or not using below code. `Date.parse()` return number if valid date otherwise 'NaN' -

```
var date = Date.parse(val);
if(isNaN(date))
 alert('This is not date');
else
 alert('This is date object');
```

For more information  - **[Date Parse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp)**

Comment: isNaN(Date.parse("hi there 1")) returns `false`!

Comment: Yes it is return false because `hmm 1` is taking as hour minute formate string and `Date.parse` is converting it to date number. This case also fails with `new Date(val)` for which you accepted answer, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/E6t4L/8/)

Comment: won't a number return a number though?  "89" is not a date

Answer (score 2):

```
function isDate(val) {
    var d = new Date(val);
    return !isNaN(d.valueOf());
}
```

Hope helps you

Comment: @PrashantJ Can you explain why unmark the answer as accept.Is it not working or something else.

Comment: `!isNaN(new Date("Hacker%1337"))` returns `true`